# how to prove $a^{p-1} + \frac{p-1}{2\cdot 1}a^{p-2} + \frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}a^{p-3} + ... + a \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading "Journey Through Genius, the great theorems of mathematics" by William Dunham. During the introduction of [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_little_theorem), it explains how [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler) first proved it in 1736. However I couldn't understand one step of it.

It says, given $p$ a prime, $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, let
$$b = a^{p-1} + \frac{p-1}{2\cdot 1}a^{p-2} + \frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}a^{p-3} + ... + a$$
, then one also has $b\in \mathbb{Z}$

This conclusion is given with only a few examples but no proof. How could it be proved?

Of course there are [other proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem), but I'm particularly interested to figure out Euler's way.

please notice that $p$ is a prime is a must.

For example if $p=4$, 
$$b = a^3 + \frac{3}{2\cdot 1}a^2 + \frac{3\cdot 2}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}a$$
is not an integer, chosen a = 13.

Comment: $\binom{p}{k} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for a prime $p$ and $1 \leqslant k \leqslant p-1$.

Comment: is this another theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Why not add an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to look at the expression $\displaystyle \frac{p(p-1)(p-2)\cdots(p-n+1)}{1.2.\cdots.n}$ combinatorially as $\displaystyle  \binom pn$. This represents the number of ways that you can choose $n$ objects out of $p$ objects when the order does not matter. Therefore it must be a natural number. Now, just by expanding $\displaystyle \binom pn$ for $n=1,\cdots,p-1$ you can factor out $p$ and obtain your expression by using the binomial theorem as $\displaystyle (a+1)^p - a^p$

**EDIT:** I guess you don't have a clear idea of what is happening here. Binomial coefficients, denoted by $\displaystyle \binom kn$ are always positive integers for the reasons that I said. Primality of $p$ comes into the play when you want to factor $p$ out of $\displaystyle \binom pn$. Since $n<p$ and $p$ is prime, $n!$ does not contain $p$ in its product. Therefore, the $p$ in the numerator does NOT get canceled and you can factor it out. That's why Fermat's little theorem is not correct for other natural numbers (A generalization exists due to Euler which uses Euler's totient function).
This proof is actually using mathematical induction on $a$. You prove that if its true for $a$, then it must be true for $a+1$ as well.

Comment: please notice $p$ is a prime is a must.

Comment: @athos: Nope. $p$ being a prime is not necessary for $\binom kn$ to be an integer. $p$ being prime is however a must for Fermat's little theorem to be true.

Comment: pls see my edited post.

Comment: thanks, now i got it. yes since $p>n$ and $p$ is a prime, it can factor out.

Answer (score 2):

Expand $(a+1)^{p}=\sum_{k=0}^{p}{p\choose k}a^k$ and note that ${p\choose k}=\frac{(p)!}{k!(p-k)!}=\frac{p(p-1)(p-2)...(p-k+1)}{k!}$ and note that $p$ and the denominator are comprime.

Comment: ${p-1\choose k}=\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-1-k)!}=\frac{(p-1)(p-2)...(p-k)}{k!}$ the last one item in the numerator is $(p-k)$, not $(p-k+1)$

Comment: of course, thanks it should be ${p\choose k}$ instead, I fixed it.

Comment: then the problem is, the coefficient, is not ${p\choose k}$, but ${p\choose k}/p$

Comment: you do know the identity ${p\choose k}={p\choose p-k}$

Comment: yes that's my difficulty. thanks for elaborating it!

Answer (score 2):

One simple proof is to use the following theorem:

> If $r$ is a real number such that $ra$ and $rb$ are both integers for
>   integers $a,b$ which are relatively prime (i.e. $(a,b) = 1$), then $r$ is an integer.

Now $\displaystyle r = \frac{(p-1)(p-2)\dots (p-k)}{(k+1)!}$ has the property that $pr$ and $(p-k-1)r$ are both binomial coefficients, and so are integers. Thus $r$ is an integer, by the above theorem.

To prove the above theorem, since $(a,b) = 1$, we have $ax + by = 1$ for some integers $x,y$. Multiplying by $r$ gives the result.

Comment: Okay. I see it. Thanks.